# flask & uwsgi: flask does not respond to request after starting a new child process

Tags: python, nginx, flask, wsgi

I am trying to deploy a flask app I wrote these days to a server using nginx, uwsgi and flask.

Upon a specific request I am doing some time-intensive calculations which flask starts a new process for (using `Process` from Python's `multiprocessing` module). Flask is able to communicate with that child process via `multiprocessing.Pipe()` to get information about the calculation status. After starting the child process flask sends a response to the client containing a unique identifier in order to request the calc's status later.
So I have two endpoints like `/api/calc/new` and `/api/calc/<id>/status` to either start a new calculation or to get its status.

Getting the status is implemented using a polling service which requests the status each 10 seconds and is fired after the `api/calc/new` request was handled by the server resp. AngularJS' promise to the desired API endpoint was resolved.

The approach described above works quite well using flask's built-in development server called by `app.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=True)`.

When deploying to nginx using uwsgi something goes wrong. After starting a new calculation by the desired request a new process seems to be spawned as the CPU load of one of the uwsgi processes shown in `top` increases to about 90 %. However, the promise does not seem to be resolved since the request is not answered by the server resp. the flask app.

So, why does this work with the built-in development server, but does not work using nginx and uwsgi? Are there any ways to get the thing working as desired in the production evironment as well?

Comment: This is a typical problem with WSGI servers if you spawn new threads or processes from your app. Use a task queue like celery instead.

Comment: So even eventlet or gunicorn do not solve that issue since those are WSGI-based as well, do they?